# isset not givig desired result using && operator

Tags: php, html

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){  
    if (isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["roll"])){ // checking whether both text boxes are filled up
            echo "$_POST[name] $_POST[roll]";   // just displays some info
       }
       else{  //not being executed when both text boxes are empty
            header("Location:interface.php");
       }    
   }
```

the above is a php code where im trying to check whether two text boxes are filled in or else i will navigate to another page. The problem is though if i fill up one text box the && condition doesn't work , it gets into the if part and echoes one value.

Comment: What do you mean by "is not giving desired result"? What _is_ desired? Certainly the `echo` below won't work like that, but that has nothing to do with the `if` conditional. You cannot refer to array elements inside a string notation like that. Instead try this: `echo $_POST['name'].' '.$_POST['roll'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is error (missing ') in:

```
echo "$_POST[name] $_POST[roll]";
```

It has to be `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['roll']`

**UPDATE**
isset() only is not enough. You should also check if it is not empty, like this:

```
if (!empty($_POST["name"]) && !empty($_POST["roll"])){
```

Comment: That is not a real answer. Though it is true what you say it does not solve the OP's problem.

Comment: echo part works fine. the problem is though if i fill up one text box the && condition doesn't work , it gets into the if part and echoes one value.

Comment: @bangBang Ah, that is another thing. Note that the values in the `$_POST` superglobal are defined even id they are empty, _if_ they are transferred from client to server. You can easily test that by dumping the `$_POST` array.

Comment: so using GET does it make any change?

Comment: @bangBang elements are set, but they are empty in your case, thats why you always get into the if statement

Comment: You can just check if both are empty, rather than isset and empty. If it's not set it's considered empty. So, you save yourself a step.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) // showing error

Comment: @bangBang like unexpected mentioned, you can use just !empty()

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&&' (T_BOOLEAN_AND) ;(

Comment: @bangBang on this? `if (!empty($_POST["name"]) && !empty($_POST["roll"])){ `

Comment: @bangBang should be ok now

Comment: ya...works fine. using GET instead of POST does it make any difference

Comment: @bangBang with GET you get all parameters visible in URL and it is useful if you want to share links, but by default POST has to be used when submitting forms